# Expectation of (sum subtract the expectation of sum)

Tags: probability, random-variable, probability-inequalities, inequality, hoeffdings-inequality

Let's say we have random variables $\mathbf{X}$, and we have $P(\mathbf{X}\in [a, b])=1$, we have $\mathbf{S}_n = \mathbf{X}_1 + \mathbf{X}_2, +\dots + \mathbf{X}_n$.

If $\mathbf{X}_1, \mathbf{X}_2, \dots, \mathbf{X}_n$ are independent, I believe we have:
$$
\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{S}_n - \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{S}_n]] = \sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{X}_i-\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{X}_i]]
$$
because I saw this as one step in the proof of Hoeffding's inequality. For example, [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality#Proof).

Can anyone help me understand why we can get this equation?

And what if $\mathbf{X}_1, \mathbf{X}_2, \dots, \mathbf{X}_n$ are not independent. Let's say we only have the first $m$ out of these $n$ variables to be independent, can we get something like: 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{X}_i-\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{X}_i]] \leq \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{S}_n - \mathbb{E}[\mathbf{S}_n]] \leq \sum_{i=1}^m\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{X}_i-\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{X}_i]]
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Independent or not, the equality always holds and also equal to $0$:

$$\begin{align}E[S_n-E[S_n]]&=E[S_n]-E[E[S_n]]=E[S_n]-E[S_n]=0\end{align}$$

Similarly,
$$\sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i-E[X_i]]=\sum_{i=1}^n (E[X_i] - E[X_i])=0$$

Comment: This is actually what I suspected, but then I don't understand why Hoeffding's inequality only applies to independent variables. This equation seems to be the only place when the proof of Hoeffding's inequality dealing with independence (expanding $\mathbf{S}_n$).

Comment: I don't see your expression in the proof in wikipedia. The expected value there have exponential term and $E[e^X]\neq e^{E[X]}$